# Setting up agent controller for tptp

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-tptp

I have already installed the tptp from eclipse's "install new software". In the next step I shoud install the agent controller.

I've downloaded the agent controller 4.7.2 und unzipped it. According to the instruction I should now:

"Run SetConfig.bat script from a command shell in the \bin directory to generate the configuration file for the Agent Controller."

When I type the SetConfig.bat in the cmd it says that setconfig.bat is not found. I have checked the bin folder and there is no such file. So I don't know what to do.

The instruction also says: "The script requires that a Java Virtual Machine (JVM) be present in the PATH environment variable." Maybe this causes the problem? But I don't know how to set the jvm into the path variable. I use win7

What should I do now? Thanx in advance!

Comment: First, document what version of eclipse you are using. Second, you should set the environment variable `%PATH%` so that it contains a path to the binary `javaw.exe` which should be located somewhere. In German Windows 7, it is named (translated) `System Control > System > Expanded > Environment Variables`. Try to open a `cmd` shell, and look if the command `java -version` produces something useful. If yes, your path contains the JVM.

Answer (score 0):

When there is no setconfig.bat in your bin folder chances are that you are using a non-windows distribution of the agent controller, especially if it contains setconfig.sh instead.

Please check and download the correct version if this is the cause.